# Best way to check whether two dates are the same calendar day in Groovy?

Tags: datetime, groovy

Obviously I could create a `Calendar` object with the date and use `get(DAY)` on it, but knowing Groovy, I would guess there is an easier, quicker way I just don't know about?

**Answer**

```
(date1..date2).size() == 1 // true if two dates are on same calendar day
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickly opened the Groovy In Action book and found the following sample that should help:

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today-1
assert (yesterday..today).size() == 2
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It just checks whether or not the difference between two dates greater than 1 day, because the default range's step is one. For example, 2014-12-08 23:00 and 2014-12-09 01:00 aren't the same day, but the size of range between them is 1.

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter and more readable then the current top answer:

```
date1 - date2 == 0 //true if two dates are on same calendar day
```